# Lufthansa connecting flight to India at Munich 40 mts in between will I be able to make it? (Travelling light-only carry on)

Tags: customs-and-immigration

single ticket(lufthansa) from new jersey to munich ; munich to bombay
 travelling light-only carry on, no check in luggage
 assuming same terminal- 2 ( both arrival and departure) at Munich
 will there be any immigration check or any waiting line to get on the Mun-Bom plane
 Indian national
 Have a  US visitors B1/B2
 No schengen visa.

Comment: @KateGregory Not quite the same. That question deals with _entering_ Schengen and then changing planes in 45 minutes. This one is merely _transiting_ Schengen without passing through immigration. Though, if 45 minutes is enough for one...

Answer (score 3):

The [Minimum Connecting Time for terminal 2 is 30 minutes](http://www.munich-airport.de/en/consumer/aufenthalt_trans/transit/minconntime/index.jsp). And that is even more than you really need, especially if you don't need to get through passport control. The terminal is designed for fast transfer time. Basically you deplane into the terminal, walk to your gate (maybe 10 minutes from end-to-end) and board again. You won't need to get through any security checks, passport control or similar.

Your only problem would be a delay on the inbound flight, but even a 20 minute delay should be fine (in most cases even checked baggage makes it in 20 minutes!). In case of a larger delay, Lufthanse often provides transportation directly from plane to plane, bypassing the terminal completely (if you would need to get through security or passport checks they even have dedicated checks on-ramp).

Answer (score 1):

The last time that I have been in MUC, passport checks were performed only when leaving the international part of the airport. So you should only have a comparably short walk between the gates.

This information may be outdated, though, but it is highly unlikely that Lufthansa is selling you a ticket with this connection if it is unlikely that you will make it.